# Is there any way to send data to pusher channel_auth_endpoint?

Tags: php, javascript, authentication, pusher

I´m developing a chat with pusher and i need to send some data to the auth endpoint, is there any way to send data and access it via POST or GET ?

```
  Pusher.channel_auth_endpoint = '/server/client_auth';
  pusher = new Pusher('public_key');
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can provide additional data to be sent to the auth endpoint when you create your `Pusher` instance e.g.

```
var authOptions = {
  headers: {
    'header-1': 'header-value-1',
    'header-2': 'header-value-1'
  },
  params: {
    'param-1': 'param-value-1',
    'param-2': 'param-value-2'
  }
};
var pusher = new Pusher( APP_KEY, { auth: authOptions } );
```

More information and use case examples can be found the Pusher docs:
http://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_connect#options_parameter

If this doesn't suit your use case I'd recommend you get in touch with [Pusher Support](http://pusher.com/support) and there may be solutions planned which better solve your requirements.